# react native webview unable to auto login

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

I'm creating an app that when the user press a button it will direct the user to a Webview. The problem is that the Webview is asking the user credentials to login the page. The user already login in the app.

Home.js

```
<View>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Details', {link: 'http://my-website.com/login-id/' + apiData.token_id + '/details', tokenID: apiData.token_id});}}>
        <Text>Details</Text> 
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Details.js

```
const { link, tokenID } = route.params;
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.white}}>
    <WebView
        style={{flex: 1, marginTop: StatusBarHeight}}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        source={{html: `<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="${link}" frameborder="0"></iframe>`}}
    />
</View>
```

Comment: You need to set some mechanism between website and application so it will work accordingly by passing parameter in URL or anything else.

Comment: @NensiKasundra can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: I don't have exact an idea as I am a mobile app developer. You can discuss with the web developer they guys will help you to achieve this thing.